# How to read a CSV file with commas within a field using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-1.6

I have a csv file containing commas within a column value. For example,

```
Column1,Column2,Column3    
123,"45,6",789
```

The values are wrapped in double quotes when they have extra commas in the data. In the above example, the values are Column1=123, Column2=45,6 and Column3=789 But, when trying to read the data, it gives me 4 values because of extra comma in Column2 field.

How to get the right values when reading this data in **PySpark**? I am using **Spark 1.6.3**

I am currently doing the below to create a rdd and then a data frame from rdd.

```
rdd = sc.textFile(input_file).map(lambda line: line.split(','))
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can directly read it to an DF using an SQLContext:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
    .options(header='true', inferschema='true', quote='"', delimiter=',')
    .load(input_file)
```

As Delimiter ',' and Quote '"' are the defaults you can also omit them. Commas inside quotes are ignored by default. An description of the parameters can be found here: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Edit:

Without relying on Databricks, I can only think of a more tricky solution - this might not be the best approach:

1. Replace commas in numbers with points
2. Split using remaining commas

So, you could keep your original code, and add the REGEX replace

```
import re
rdd = sc.textFile(input_file).map(lambda line: (re.sub(r'\"(\d+),(\d+)\"',r'\1.\2', line)).split(','))
df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
```

The supplied REGEX also gets rid of the double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tobi. Are you saying we can't do this with Spark 1.6. Your suggestion works only when I upgrade spark to 2.0. Please advice.

Comment: The link I provided specifically talks about Spark 1.6. So this should work with Spark 1.6.

Comment: I looked at it. Yeah it is for Spark 1.6.. 

but Is there way to do this without using databricks libraries ?