# Ignore backslash-quote inside the csv field PySpark

Tags: csv, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm trying to read CSV using spark in databricks:

```
spark.read.format('csv').option('header', 'true')\
  .option('inferschema', True)\
  .option('quote', '\"')\
  .option("escape", '\"')\
  .load(path_to_csv)\
  .createOrReplaceTempView('table_name')
```

But it doesn't read correcrtly following line:

""Sample Company",LLC"

Instead of getting:

```
+------------------------+
|                   col1 |
+------------------------+
|    "Sample Company",LLC|
+------------------------+
```

I get following result:

```
+------------------+--------------------+
|             col1 |                col2|
+------------------+--------------------+
|""Sample Company" | LLC"               |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

Tried different combinations of "quotes" and "escape" options, but nothing works so far.

Comment: Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704937/how-to-read-a-csv-file-with-commas-within-a-field-using-pyspark